# Process stack items in several threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, concurrency

I have a [ConcurrentStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331.aspx), each item of which is URL to some web resource. Also I have N threads (actually `Tasks`), each of which pop one item from the stack process and add the result(the result is collection) to this stack or to other output queue depending on some criteria. This should be done, until stack become empty.

What is the more elegant way to recognize the end of this process and stop this tasks? In the other words, how to recognize that the stack is empty and there is no executing task that will add more items to the stack

Comment: You are describing how the consumers work but your question is about the producers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminating condition seems to be when all the tasks reading from the stack are *all* waiting for an item to be piled up the stack. Of course, this can only happen if you provide a way for your task to passively wait for that event. As suggested by other answers, you could use `BlockingCollection` on top of the `ConcurrentStack` class to implement synchronization.

Regarding termination, the simplest way is to have a task (the termination task) waiting for that condition, and all other tasks manipulate an integer representing the number of tasks waiting, incrementing it before blocking on the collection, and decrementing it when obtaining an item. When that number reaches the total number of possible readers for the stack, the task currently trying to get an item triggers the condition variable before blocking on the collection, which will wake up the termination thread.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a ConcurrentStack, which implements [IProducerConsumerCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd287147.aspx), you could wrap it with a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd267312.aspx) (by creating one using [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287133.aspx)). This provides a [CompleteAdding()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx) method which allows you to indicate the end of data.

The underlying IProducerConsumerCollection will be used to store the items, so it will still behave like a stack in terms of it being LIFO.

You would need to switch to using one of the [GetConsumingEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381957.aspx) overloads to consume the data. I find this to be a most elegant and powerful way to handle graceful task termination.

Perhaps this might work for you?

Comment: Thanks for answer, I didn't know about the possibility to extend BlockingCollection as a stack, but however all of my threads don't know if it is time to call CompleteAdding or not, because no one knows if the others are going to add more items or not

Comment: Well *something* must know - and that something must call `CompleteAdding()`.